# Mixed Groovy + Java project causes string syntax clashes

Tags: java, string, groovy, compiler-errors

I have a project with Java and Groovy files, wanting to compile both into .class.

My Groovy classes use Java classes. One of Java classes contains annotation

```
@ConfigPartDescriptor(
    name = "Mail Service ${jndiName}"
)
@XmlRootElement(name = "mbean")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public final class MailServiceBean extends MBeanJaxbBase<MailServiceBean> implements IConfigFragment, Origin.Wise {
```

which is OK for Java, but Groovy, despite it's not compiling the file, complains:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:compile (compile-groovy-classes) on project AsMigrator: startup failed:
file:/home/ondra/work/AS/Migration/git-repo/src/main/java/org/jboss/loom/migrators/_groovy/TestJaxbBean.groovy: 20: Expected 'Mail Service $jndiName' to be an inline constant of type java.lang.String in @org.jboss.loom.spi.ann.ConfigPartDescriptor
@ line 20, column 12.
name = "Mail Service ${jndiName}"
```

Using Maven GMaven plugin. (Eclipse Groovy compiler fails on the same thing.)

My guess is that Groovy compiler processes the annotations, and seeing `${...}`, it creates a `GroovyString` instead of `String`. And then typecheck fails.

**How can I fix this?** I could use different syntax, e.g. %{...} but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: What's on line 20 of TestJaxbBean.groovy?

Comment: *Forehead slap* You're right. The same string is contained in the groovy script. I overlooked it as it was hidden by IDE's auto-collapse :)

Comment: I've re-instated my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried single quotes so Groovy doesn't template it?

```
@ConfigPartDescriptor( name = 'Mail Service ${jndiName}' )
```